# Controlar error al conectase a mi base de datos MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente código para realizar la conexión a mi base de datos MySQL, lo que quiero es controlar el error que me aparece cuando intento ejecutar el programa, me salta el error/aviso de que el Xampp esta apagado. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de controlarlo mediante por ejemplo un JOptionpane con un mensaje que diga: la base da datos no esta iniciada.

Código para la conexión:

```
public class ConexionBD
{
    public Connection conexion=null;
    public Statement sentencia=null;        //Se usa para enviar sentencias SQL a la BD
    public ResultSet resultado=null;        //Contendrá los datos devueltos de una sentencia SQL

    public ConexionBD()
    {
        conectarBD();
    }
    public void conectarBD()
    {
        // Conectar con MySql
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/concesionario";

        // Cargar el driver y se genera una nueva instancia y crear conexión
        try 
        {               
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            // Crear sentencia
            sentencia = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void cerrarConexionBD()
    {
        try 
        {
            resultado.close();
            sentencia.close();
            conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}                  
    }
}
```

Mensaje de error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:781)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   bbdd.ConexionBD.conectarBD(ConexionBD.java:28)    at
>   bbdd.ConexionBD.(ConexionBD.java:17)    at
>   clientes.FormularioClientes.(FormularioClientes.java:58)    at
>   panelconcesionario.Concesionario.(Concesionario.java:16)    at
>   main.Main.main(Main.java:8) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al finalizar el primer catch del método ConnectarBD, pones otro catch con la excepción que te da y el JOptionPane dentro del catch.

```
    try{               
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        // Crear sentencia
        sentencia = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        } 
          catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
          catch (ExcepcionQueQuieresControlar ex) { JOptionPane.... ; }
```

Comment: No me funciona, sigue apareciendo el error.

Comment: Sera por que nos has puesto la excepcion correcta, ese metodo de control tiene que funcionar. "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException" pones eso en la expecion del catch? O "CommunicationsException"?

Comment: Sino prueba co  SQLException